# Eloquent ORM multiple relationships

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

There are three tables.

```
users:
 - ...
 - some_param

admins:
 - ...
 - club_id
 - some_param

clubs:
 - id
 - title
```

Each user can have multiple admins (related by some_param), each admin can have multiple clubs, and I want to get each club's title.

So I defined a relations:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function admins() {
        return $this->hasMany('Admin', 'some_param', 'some_param');
    }
}

class Admin extends Eloquent {    
    public function clubs() {
        $this->hasMany('Club', 'id', 'club_id');
    }
}
```

And want to use it in template:

```
@foreach($user->admins as $admin)
    @foreach($admin->clubs as $club)
        {{ $club->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But I'm getting an error: `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` at line `@foreach($admin->clubs as $club)`.

What's I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your following function:

```
public function clubs() {
    $this->hasMany('Club', 'id', 'club_id');
}
```

You didn't `return` so use `return` like this:

```
public function clubs() {
    return $this->hasMany('Club', 'id', 'club_id');
}
```

Also, when getting `User` collection in `$user` variable, try to use [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading), for example:

```
$user = User::with('admins.clubs')->find(1);
```

This will reduce the queries.